# inlining failed in call to always_inline, target specific option mismatch in Qt

Tags: c++, aes, qt-creator

I am doing AES encryption using AES instruction set in C++ in QtCreator, this is my code:

```
void aes256_enc(int8_t *plainText, int8_t *cipherText, __m256i *exp_enc_key)
{
    __m256i m = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i *) plainText);

    m = _mm256_xor_si256(m, exp_enc_key[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        m = _mm256_aesenc_epi128(m, exp_enc_key[i]);
    }
    m = _mm256_aesenclast_epi128(m, exp_enc_key[10]);

    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i *) cipherText, m);
}
```

And this is in my `.pro` file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS +=-march=native -maes

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
    aes256.cpp

HEADERS += \
    aes256.h
```

But I still get error like:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/include/vaesintrin.h:50: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘__m256i _mm256_aesenc_epi128(__m256i, __m256i)’: target specific option mismatch
   50 | _mm256_aesenc_epi128 (__m256i __A, __m256i __B)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My CPU is i5-4670.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.pro` file add this line if your target processor support AVX-512 aka vaes:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mvaes
```

In `vaesintrin.h` this define seems to require vaes

```
/* Default attributes for YMM forms. */
#define __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS __attribute__((__always_inline__, __nodebug__, __target__("vaes"), __min_vector_width__(256)))
```

As your processor  i5-4670 [does not support it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#CPUs_with_AVX-512), try this :

```
DEFINES += "NO_AVX512=1"
```

Comment: ***Why?*** What does this define do that solves the problem? Please take some time to [read about how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thank you for your comment. The answer is edited now.

Comment: @SoheilArmin Thank you, on i5 4670 it works, but on i7 8550U I get ":-1: error: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mvaes’; did you mean ‘-maes’?".

Comment: @tomsk, no I did mean ```-mvaes```. Seems that  i7 8550U does not support it.

Comment: @SoheilArmin but i7 8550U should suppports AES-NI.

Comment: @tomsk, run ```# sudo sort -u /proc/crypto | grep module``` and check if you have ```module       : aesni_intel```. I don't think that it has anything to do with the compilation anyways. check this link as well https://embarc.org/man-pages/gcc/x86-Options.html

Comment: @SoheilArmin yes I have:
`tomsk@tomsk-Ntb:~$ sudo sort -u /proc/crypto | grep module
[sudo] password for tomsk: 
module       : aesni_intel
module       : aes_x86_64
module       : arc4
module       : ccm
module       : crc32_pclmul
module       : crct10dif_pclmul
module       : ecdh_generic
module       : ghash_clmulni_intel
module       : kernel
module       : pcbc`

Comment: @SoheilArmin `g++ -o test main.cpp -march=native -maes -mrdrnd -msse4.1 -mvaes` and error:
`g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mvaes’; did you mean ‘-maes’?`

Comment: add mtune=intel

Comment: @SoheilArmin Still: 
`g++ -o test main.cpp -march=native -maes -mrdrnd -msse4.1 -mtune=intel -mvaes` error: 
`g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mvaes’; did you mean ‘-maes’?`

Comment: what about -maes? with tune=intel

Comment: @SoheilArmin `g++ -o test main.cpp -march=native -maes -mrdrnd -msse4.2 -tune=intel -mvaes
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-tune=intel’; did you mean ‘-masm=intel’?
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mvaes’; did you mean ‘-maes’?`

Comment: look at this : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/g++.1.html . -mvaes should be available for x86, check your g++ version. and forget -mtune

Comment: @SoheilArmin `gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)`

Comment: @tomsk, you gcc version is ok. how do you target that specific processor?

Comment: @SoheilArmin I don't know what do you mean, I use parameter `-march=native` in g++ parameters as you could see before.

Comment: @tomsk, you said that it does not work on  i7 8550U. how did you test it on i5 ?

Comment: @SoheilArmin For i5 I use arguments `g++ -o test main.cpp -march=native -maes -mvaes`